# Change date and time entered by user to different timezone in React Sharepoint SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I am trying to change date entered by user to different timezone. Right now it only for default value.
But I want to change the date which will be entered by user in React Sharepoint Framework SPFx

```
<select onChange={this.submit}>
      <option value="-4">Virginia</option>
      <option value="-7">California</option>
      <option value="-4">New York</option>
      <option value="-4">Georgia</option>
    </select>

<DateTimePicker placeholder={Date()} label="DateTime Picker - 12h" dateConvention={DateConvention.DateTime} value={this.state.temp} onChange={this.dateChange}/>
    
submit = (event) => {
var dt = new Date();
var utc = dt.getTime() + (dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var fdt = new Date(utc + (3600000 * event.target.value));
console.log("Time: " + fdt.toLocaleString());
this.setState({temp:fdt});
console.log({temp:fdt});
```

Comment: Where can I find the DateTimePicker component?Anf you want to get the date value entered by user?

Comment: Yes, in react spfx and there are few additional things I want to add like disabling Weekend and highlighting modified value.

Comment: I got this DateTimePicker component from pnp spfx controls react

Comment: It seems that this component can not disable weekend.There is no property about this.You can refer to official document:https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/DateTimePicker/

Comment: Ohk thanks.....then I must use another date-time picker